# Mean average Precision(what happen if there is no prediction at all)

Tags: object-detection, metrics

Mean Average Precision Confusion. (What happen if the model make no predictiona at all)

So , I am trying to understand what mean Average Precision. What I understand so far. First it will check if the predicted box and the ground box overlapped by certain IOU Threshold. Then , it will check the predicted box confidence score and sort them in the confidence order. Then it will calculate the AP at different recall value such as the precision-recall curve. So basically, what I understand is that of all the prediction that the model made, it will sort the prediction box based on the confidence score and calculate the PR curve.

I am using this as a reference to understand mAP (https://towardsdatascience.com/breaking-down-mean-average-precision-map-ae462f623a52)

But what will happen if the model make no prediction at all? or If the model makes only one prediction and that prediction is correct. Then is is the mAP one in this case? Because we will sort them based on model predicted box and since the model get the predicted the box right the mAP will be one.

Comment: If the model makes only one prediction and it is correct (IOU is greater than 0.5 and classification is correct for example), depending how many groundtruths are there on the image, the AP is different. If the image contains 2 groundtruths, then the Precision = 1, but Recall = 0.5, the AP is not 1, and mAP would be less than 1 too.

Comment: Oh shoot , I forgot to think about the recall. Thanks for the help